# Need advice for efficient solution with operations on array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for an efficient solution to isolate an element of array and edit it:
My array is:

```php
$starting_array = array_slice($main_array, 8, 1);
```

Where value of array element is

```
print_r($starting_array); 

// output:
Array (
    [key] => A;B;C;D;E;
)
```

I have to get this result:

```php
$ending_array = Array ( 
    [A] => 0 
    [B] => 1 
    [C] => 2 
    [D] => 3 
    [E] => 4 
)
```

I have followed this approach:

```php
$middle1 = implode(" ", $starting_array);
$middle2 = explode(";", $middle1);
$ending_array = array_flip($middle2);
```

Is there a more efficient solution to achieve the same result?

Comment: `$starting_array = Array ([key] => A;B;C;D;E;);` or what?

Comment: You answered your question by yourself and no there is no more efficient solution to reach your goals. But i do not understand why you need `implode` .. you `explode` and `array_flip` thats fine. -> You have to trim the last semicolon otherwise you receive a empty array element..

Comment: @AbraCadaver Is result of  print_r($starting_array);

Comment: Given that `$middle1 = implode(" ", $array);` doesn't make any sense but this rest looks fine.

Comment: @ChrisG I use implode because without it I get this error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given. The value of initial array element (A;B;C;D;E;)  is a string

Answer (score 0):

@AbraCadaver and @ChrisG, I realize I had made a mistake. $middle1 is now correct. Thanks to both!

Comment: `$starting_array['key'] ---> A;B;C;D;E;`